# Php variables in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I've came across following problem:

I have this query:
`SELECT firstName
FROM users
WHERE id = '$id'`

This query works perfect.
However, I want to replace 'firstName' with a php variable '$a'. But when executing the query like that will return me the string 'firstName'. How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: select \`$id\` from users

Comment: for that you have to update...not select

Comment: You've probably quoted your `$a` wrong, there should possibly be backticks bit no double or single quotes around firstname in the resulting string.

Comment: some people posts questions but never care the responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want something like

$sql = "Select ".$a." from users Where id = '".$id."';

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = 'SELECT `' . $a . '` FROM Users WHERE id = "' . $id . '";
---------------^----------^ these are the characters you need
```